# Booting linux kernel via bootftp

Tags: boot, embedded-linux

I have [P2020RDB board](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/power-architecture-processors/qoriq-platforms/p-series/p2020-reference-design-board:P2020RDB) with `U-Boot 2013.01-00115` installed with custom embedded Linux distro and everything works fine for now. However, for some testing purposes, I need *elegant way* of switching different images at boot time. Since `U-Boot` does not support selecting image like `LILO` (at least I havent found a way of implementing such task), I've setup [TFTPD-HPA](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=tftpd-hpa) server on my **Debian development machine** and copied all kernels into `/srv/tftp` directory:

```
testuser@debianvirtual:/srv/tftp$ ls
total 8656
   4 drwxrwxrwx 2 nobody  root       4096 Mar  8 09:36 ./
   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root       4096 Mar  8 09:21 ../
4304 -rw-r--r-- 1 testuser testuser 4406711 Mar  3 10:46 uImage_spe_on_emulation_off
  16 -rw-r--r-- 1 testuser testuser   13899 Mar  3 10:45 uImage_spe_on_emulation_off.dtb
4312 -rw-r--r-- 1 testuser testuser 4411448 Mar  3 10:07 uImage_spe_on_emulation_unimplemented
  16 -rw-r--r-- 1 testuser testuser   13899 Mar  3 10:08 uImage_spe_on_emulation_unimplemented.dtb
```

The server works and ethernet settings on both sided (workstation and board) seem fine since I can download image to board from its serial console:

```
=> tftpboot uImage_spe_on_emulation_unimplemented
Speed: 1000, full duplex
Using eTSEC1 device
TFTP from server 192.168.35.213; our IP address is 192.168.35.106
Filename 'uImage_spe_on_emulation_unimplemented'.
Load address: 0x1000000
Loading: #################################################################
         #################################################################
         #################################################################
         #################################################################
         #########################################
         2.6 MiB/s
done
Bytes transferred = 4411448 (435038 hex)
```

Now, how do I initiate boot process with selected, i.e., downloaded image? If I try:

```
=> bootp 0x01000000 192.168.35.231:uImage_spe_on_emulation_unimplemented
```

I get:

```
Speed: 1000, full duplex
BOOTP broadcast 1
BOOTP broadcast 2
BOOTP broadcast 3
BOOTP broadcast 4
BOOTP broadcast 5

Retry count exceeded; starting again
eTSEC2 Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to complete......... TIMEOUT !
eTSEC2: No link.
eTSEC3 Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to complete......... TIMEOUT !
eTSEC3: No link.
Speed: 1000, full duplex
```

How do I properly initiate boot process with downloaded image?

**ADDENDUM 1:**
I've tried the hint I've got from user @sawdust:

```
=> bootm 1000000
```

and I get:

```
WARNING: adjusting available memory to 30000000
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 01000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-3.12.37-rt51+g43cecda
   Created:      2017-03-03   8:26:06 UTC
   Image Type:   PowerPC Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    4411384 Bytes = 4.2 MiB
   Load Address: 00000000
   Entry Point:  00000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK
```

which is ok, creation date is ok, however, after upper message boot process stalls.

**ADDENDUM 2**: Output of `printenv` command:

```
=> printenv
$othbootargs ramdisk_size=$ramdisk_size;tftp $ramdiskaddr $ramdiskfile;tftp
baudrate=115200
bdev=sda1
bootargs=root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootfstype=ext2 rootdelay=3 console=ttyS0,115200
bootcmd=mmcinfo; ext2load mmc 0:1 0x1000000 /boot/uImage; ext2load mmc 0:1 0xc00000 /boot/dtb_file; bootm 0x1000000 - c00000
bootdelay=10
bootfile=uImage
console=$consoledev,$baudrate $othbootargs;tftp $loadaddr $bootfile;tftp
consoledev=ttyS0
eth1addr=00:04:9F:04:9E:7B
eth2addr=00:04:9F:04:9E:7C
ethact=eTSEC1
ethaddr=00:04:9F:04:9E:7A
fdtaddr=c00000
fileaddr=1000000
filesize=435038
gatewayip=192.168.35.1
hostname=testhostname
hwconfig=usb1:dr_mode=host,phy_type=ulpi
ip=$ipaddr:$serverip:$gatewayip:$netmask:$hostname:$netdev:off
ipaddr=192.168.35.106
ipaddr=192.168.35.143
jffs2nand=mtdblock9
jffs2nor=mtdblock3
loadaddr=1000000
map_lowernorbank=i2c dev 1; i2c mw 18 1 02 1; i2c mw 18 3 fd 1
map_uppernorbank=i2c dev 1; i2c mw 18 1 00 1; i2c mw 18 3 fd 1
nandboot=i2c dev 1; i2c mw 18 1 0xe8 1; i2c mw 18 3 0x03 1; reset
nandbootaddr=100000
nandfdtaddr=80000
netdev=eth0
nfsboot=setenv bootargs root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=$serverip:$rootpath
norboot=i2c dev 1; i2c mw 18 1 0xc8 1; i2c mw 18 3 0x03 1; reset
norbootaddr=ef080000
norfdtaddr=ef040000
pciboot=i2c dev 1; i2c mw 18 1 0xa8 1; i2c mw 18 3 0x03 1; reset
ramboot=setenv bootargs root=/dev/ram rw console=$consoledev,$baudrate
ramdisk_size=120000
ramdiskaddr=2000000
ramdiskfile=rootfs.ext2.gz.uboot
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2
rootpath=/opt/nfsroot
sataboot=setenv bootargs root=/dev/sda3 rw console=$consoledev,$baudrate
sdboot=i2c dev 1; i2c mw 18 1 0x68 1; i2c mw 18 3 0x03 1; reset
serverip=192.168.35.213
spiboot=i2c dev 1; i2c mw 18 1 0x28 1; i2c mw 18 3 0x03 1; reset
stderr=serial
stdin=serial
stdout=serial
tftpflash=tftpboot $loadaddr $uboot; protect off 0xeff80000 +$filesize; erase
uboot=u-boot.bin
vscfw_addr=ef000000

Environment size: 1976/8188 bytes
=>
```

and normal boot sequence output:

```
U-Boot 2013.01-00115-g831b30d (Jun 14 2013 - 21:48:56)

CPU0:  P2020E, Version: 2.1, (0x80ea0021)
Core:  E500, Version: 5.1, (0x80211051)
Clock Configuration:
       CPU0:1200 MHz, CPU1:1200 MHz,
       CCB:600  MHz,
       DDR:400  MHz (800 MT/s data rate) (Asynchronous), LBC:37.500 MHz
L1:    D-cache 32 kB enabled
       I-cache 32 kB enabled
Board: P2020RDB-PCA CPLD: V4.2 PCBA: V4.0
rom_loc: nor upper bank
SD/MMC : 4-bit Mode
eSPI : Enabled
I2C:   ready
SPI:   ready
DRAM:  Detected UDIMM
1 GiB (DDR3, 64-bit, CL=6, ECC off)
Flash: 16 MiB
L2:    512 KB enabled
NAND:  128 MiB
MMC:  FSL_SDHC: 0
PCIe1: Root Complex of mini PCIe SLOT, no link, regs @ 0xffe0a000
PCIe1: Bus 00 - 00
PCIe2: Root Complex of PCIe SLOT, x1, regs @ 0xffe09000
  02:00.0     - 1095:3132 - Mass storage controller
PCIe2: Bus 01 - 02
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   eTSEC2 is in sgmii mode.
uploading VSC7385 microcode from ef000000
PHY reset timed out
eTSEC1, eTSEC2, eTSEC3
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
Device: FSL_SDHC
Manufacturer ID: 27
OEM: 5048
Name: SD8GB
Tran Speed: 50000000
Rd Block Len: 512
SD version 2.0
High Capacity: Yes
Capacity: 7.4 GiB
Bus Width: 4-bit
4447010 bytes read in 256 ms (16.6 MiB/s)
13899 bytes read in 80 ms (168.9 KiB/s)
WARNING: adjusting available memory to 30000000
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 01000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-3.12.37-rt51+g43cecda
   Created:      2017-02-22   8:19:07 UTC
   Image Type:   PowerPC Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    4446946 Bytes = 4.2 MiB
   Load Address: 00000000
   Entry Point:  00000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 00c00000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x00c00000
   Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 03ff9000, end 03fff64a ... OK
WARNING: could not find compatible node fsl-usb2-dr: FDT_ERR_NOTFOUND.
Using P2020RDB-PC machine description
Memory CAM mapping: 256/256/256 Mb, residual: 256Mb
Linux version 3.12.37-rt51+g43cecda (markofr@debianvirtual) (gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) ) #7 SMP PREEMPT RT Wed Feb 22 09:18:46 CET 2017
CPU maps initialized for 1 thread per core
setup_arch: bootmem
mpc85xx_rdb_setup_arch()
arch: exit
bootconsole [udbg0] enabled
mpc85xx_qe_init: Could not find Quicc Engine node
MPC85xx RDB board from Freescale Semiconductor
Zone ranges:
  DMA      [mem 0x00000000-0x2fffffff]
  Normal   empty
Movable zone start for each node
Early memory node ranges
  node   0: [mem 0x00000000-0x2fffffff]
MMU: Allocated 1088 bytes of context maps for 255 contexts
PERCPU: Embedded 8 pages/cpu @c0eed000 s8640 r8192 d15936 u32768
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 195072
Kernel command line: root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootfstype=ext2 rootdelay=3 console=ttyS0,115200
PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1572864 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
Sorting __ex_table...
Memory: 703196K/786432K available (6408K kernel code, 340K rwdata, 1852K rodata, 240K init, 228K bss, 83236K reserved)
Kernel virtual memory layout:
  * 0xfffdf000..0xfffff000  : fixmap
  * 0xfdffc000..0xfe000000  : early ioremap
  * 0xf1000000..0xfdffc000  : vmalloc & ioremap
SLUB: HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=2, Nodes=1
Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
        RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
NR_IRQS:512 nr_irqs:512 16
mpic: Setting up MPIC " OpenPIC  " version 1.2 at ffe40000, max 2 CPUs
mpic: ISU size: 256, shift: 8, mask: ff
mpic: Initializing for 256 sources
mpc85xx_rdb_pic_init: Could not find qe-ic node
clocksource: timebase mult[d555555] shift[24] registered
Console: colour dummy device 80x25
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
mpic: requesting IPIs...
Brought up 2 CPUs
devtmpfs: initialized
NET: Registered protocol family 16

Found FSL PCI host bridge at 0x00000000ffe09000. Firmware bus number: 0->1
PCI host bridge /pcie@ffe09000 (primary) ranges:
 MEM 0x00000000a0000000..0x00000000bfffffff -> 0x00000000a0000000
  IO 0x00000000ffc10000..0x00000000ffc1ffff -> 0x0000000000000000
/pcie@ffe09000: PCICSRBAR @ 0xfff00000
/pcie@ffe09000: Setting PCI inbound window greater than memory size
Found FSL PCI host bridge at 0x00000000ffe0a000. Firmware bus number: 0->0
PCI host bridge /pcie@ffe0a000  ranges:
 MEM 0x0000000080000000..0x000000009fffffff -> 0x0000000080000000
  IO 0x00000000ffc00000..0x00000000ffc0ffff -> 0x0000000000000000
/pcie@ffe0a000: PCICSRBAR @ 0xfff00000
/pcie@ffe0a000: Setting PCI inbound window greater than memory size
PCI: Probing PCI hardware
fsl-pci ffe09000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0xffff]
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xa0000000-0xbfffffff]
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
pci 0000:00:00.0: ignoring class 0x0b2000 (doesn't match header type 01)
pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01-ff]
fsl-pci ffe0a000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0001:02
pci_bus 0001:02: root bus resource [io  0x20000-0x2ffff] (bus address [0x0000-0xffff])
pci_bus 0001:02: root bus resource [mem 0x80000000-0x9fffffff]
pci_bus 0001:02: root bus resource [bus 02-ff]
pci 0001:02:00.0: ignoring class 0x0b2000 (doesn't match header type 01)
pci 0001:02:00.0: bridge configuration invalid ([bus 00-00]), reconfiguring
pci 0001:02:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03-ff]
pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 9: can't assign mem pref (size 0x100000)
pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xa0080000-0xa00fffff pref]
pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [io  0x0000-0xffff]
pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xa0000000-0xbfffffff]
pci_bus 0000:00: Some PCI device resources are unassigned, try booting with pci=realloc
pci 0001:02:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
pci 0001:02:00.0:   bridge window [io  0x20000-0x2ffff]
pci 0001:02:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x80000000-0x9fffffff]
mpic-msgr ffe41400.message: Found 0 message registers
mpic-msgr ffe41400.message: Of-device full name /soc@ffe00000/message@41400
mpic-msgr ffe41400.message: Failed to find message register block alias
fsl-l2ctlr ffe20000.l2-cache-controller: Entire L2 as cache, provide valid sram address and size
fsl-l2ctlr: probe of ffe20000.l2-cache-controller failed with error -22
bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
Freescale Elo series DMA driver
fsl-elo-dma ffe0c300.dma: #0 (fsl,eloplus-dma-channel), irq 76
fsl-elo-dma ffe0c300.dma: #1 (fsl,eloplus-dma-channel), irq 77
fsl-elo-dma ffe0c300.dma: #2 (fsl,eloplus-dma-channel), irq 78
fsl-elo-dma ffe0c300.dma: #3 (fsl,eloplus-dma-channel), irq 79
fsl-elo-dma ffe21300.dma: #0 (fsl,eloplus-dma-channel), irq 20
fsl-elo-dma ffe21300.dma: #1 (fsl,eloplus-dma-channel), irq 21
fsl-elo-dma ffe21300.dma: #2 (fsl,eloplus-dma-channel), irq 22
fsl-elo-dma ffe21300.dma: #3 (fsl,eloplus-dma-channel), irq 23
qe_init: Could not find Quicc Engine node
SCSI subsystem initialized
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
PTP clock support registered
EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
Switched to clocksource timebase
NET: Registered protocol family 2
TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
TCP: reno registered
UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 40960 bytes)
UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 40960 bytes)
NET: Registered protocol family 1
RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
RPC: Registered udp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
Freescale PMC driver
audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
type=2000 audit(0.597:1): initialized
HugeTLB registered 1 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 4 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 16 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 64 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 256 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 1 GB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
Key type id_resolver registered
Key type id_legacy registered
Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
NTFS driver 2.1.30 [Flags: R/O].
jffs2: version 2.2. (NAND) © 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
msgmni has been set to 1502
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 2 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
serial8250.0: ttyS0 at MMIO 0xffe04500 (irq = 42, base_baud = 37500000) is a 16550A
console [ttyS0] enabled, bootconsole disabled
console [ttyS0] enabled, bootconsole disabled
serial8250.0: ttyS1 at MMIO 0xffe04600 (irq = 42, base_baud = 37500000) is a 16550A
Generic non-volatile memory driver v1.1
brd: module loaded
loop: module loaded
nbd: registered device at major 43
st: Version 20101219, fixed bufsize 32768, s/g segs 256
pci 0000:00:00.0: enabling device (0106 -> 0107)
scsi0 : sata_sil24
scsi1 : sata_sil24
ata1: SATA max UDMA/100 host m128@0xa0000000 port 0xa0004000 irq 24
ata2: SATA max UDMA/100 host m128@0xa0000000 port 0xa0006000 irq 24
ef000000.nor: Found 1 x16 devices at 0x0 in 16-bit bank. Manufacturer ID 0x000001 Chip ID 0x002101
Amd/Fujitsu Extended Query Table at 0x0040
  Amd/Fujitsu Extended Query version 1.5.
number of CFI chips: 1
5 ofpart partitions found on MTD device ef000000.nor
Creating 5 MTD partitions on "ef000000.nor":
0x000000000000-0x000000040000 : "NOR Vitesse-7385 Firmware"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000040000-0x000000080000 : "NOR DTB Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000080000-0x000000500000 : "NOR Linux Kernel Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000500000-0x000000ec0000 : "NOR JFFS2 Root File System"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000ec0000-0x000001000000 : "NOR U-Boot Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
ONFI param page 0 valid
ONFI flash detected
NAND device: Manufacturer ID: 0x2c, Chip ID: 0xf1 (Micron MT29F1G08ABAEAWP), 128MiB, page size: 2048, OOB size: 64
Bad block table found at page 65472, version 0x01
Bad block table found at page 65408, version 0x01
6 ofpart partitions found on MTD device ff800000.flash
Creating 6 MTD partitions on "ff800000.flash":
0x000000000000-0x000000100000 : "NAND U-Boot Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000100000-0x000000200000 : "NAND DTB Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000200000-0x000000600000 : "NAND Linux Kernel Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000600000-0x000000a00000 : "NAND Compressed RFS Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000a00000-0x000001100000 : "NAND JFFS2 Root File System"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000001100000-0x000002000000 : "NAND Writable User area"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
eLBC NAND device at 0xff800000, bank 1
fsl_espi ffe07000.spi: master is unqueued, this is deprecated
m25p80 spi32766.0: found s25fl128s, expected m25p80
m25p80 spi32766.0: s25fl128s (16384 Kbytes)
5 ofpart partitions found on MTD device spi32766.0
Creating 5 MTD partitions on "spi32766.0":
0x000000000000-0x000000100000 : "SPI U-Boot Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000100000-0x000000180000 : "SPI DTB Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000180000-0x000000580000 : "SPI Linux Kernel Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000580000-0x000000980000 : "SPI Compressed RFS Image"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
0x000000980000-0x000001000000 : "SPI JFFS2 RFS"
ftl_cs: FTL header not found.
fsl_espi ffe07000.spi: at 0xf10f0000 (irq = 59)
libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
libphy: Freescale PowerQUICC MII Bus: probed
libphy: Freescale PowerQUICC MII Bus: probed
fsl-gianfar ffe24000.ethernet: enabled errata workarounds, flags: 0x4
fsl-gianfar ffe24000.ethernet eth0: mac: 00:04:9f:04:9e:7a
fsl-gianfar ffe24000.ethernet eth0: Running with NAPI enabled
fsl-gianfar ffe24000.ethernet eth0: RX BD ring size for Q[0]: 256
fsl-gianfar ffe24000.ethernet eth0: TX BD ring size for Q[0]: 256
fsl-gianfar ffe25000.ethernet: enabled errata workarounds, flags: 0x4
fsl-gianfar ffe25000.ethernet eth1: mac: 00:04:9f:04:9e:7b
fsl-gianfar ffe25000.ethernet eth1: Running with NAPI enabled
fsl-gianfar ffe25000.ethernet eth1: RX BD ring size for Q[0]: 256
fsl-gianfar ffe25000.ethernet eth1: TX BD ring size for Q[0]: 256
fsl-gianfar ffe26000.ethernet: enabled errata workarounds, flags: 0x4
fsl-gianfar ffe26000.ethernet eth2: mac: 00:04:9f:04:9e:7c
fsl-gianfar ffe26000.ethernet eth2: Running with NAPI enabled
fsl-gianfar ffe26000.ethernet eth2: RX BD ring size for Q[0]: 256
fsl-gianfar ffe26000.ethernet eth2: TX BD ring size for Q[0]: 256
pps pps0: new PPS source ptp0
ucc_geth_driver: QE UCC Gigabit Ethernet Controller
e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 2.3.2-k
e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2013 Intel Corporation.
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: Freescale On-Chip EHCI Host Controller
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: irq 28, io mem 0xffe22000
fsl-ehci fsl-ehci.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
usb usb1: Product: Freescale On-Chip EHCI Host Controller
usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.12.37-rt51+g43cecda ehci_hcd
usb usb1: SerialNumber: fsl-ehci.0
hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
i2c /dev entries driver
mpc-i2c ffe03000.i2c: timeout 1000000 us
mpc-i2c ffe03100.i2c: timeout 1000000 us
sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
/soc@ffe00000/sdhc@2e000: voltage-ranges unspecified
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
mmc0: SDHCI controller on ffe2e000.sdhc [ffe2e000.sdhc] using DMA
talitos ffe30000.crypto: hwrng
talitos ffe30000.crypto: max_xor_srcs 6
talitos ffe30000.crypto: fsl,sec3.1 algorithms registered in /proc/crypto
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: USB HID core driver
ipip: IPv4 over IPv4 tunneling driver
TCP: cubic registered
Initializing XFRM netlink socket
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
NET: Registered protocol family 10
sit: IPv6 over IPv4 tunneling driver
NET: Registered protocol family 17
NET: Registered protocol family 15
Key type dns_resolver registered
/home/markofr/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/build_barebone/tmp/work-shared/p2020rdb/kernel-source/drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
Waiting 3 sec before mounting root device...
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using fsl-ehci
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 0007
mmcblk0: mmc0:0007 SD8GB 7.42 GiB
 mmcblk0: p1 p2
usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608
usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using fsl-ehci
usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=125f, idProduct=c93a
usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-1.4: Product: A-DATA USB Flash Drive
usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: A-DATA
usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: f8a0f742b086a5
usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi2 : usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0
ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 0)
ata1.00: ATA-7: FUJITSU MHV2120BH PL, 00840029, max UDMA/100
ata1.00: 234441648 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      FUJITSU MHV2120B 0084 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 234441648 512-byte logical blocks: (120 GB/111 GiB)
sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     A-DATA   USB Flash Drive  0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 7892087 512-byte logical blocks: (4.04 GB/3.76 GiB)
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
 sda: sda1
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
 sdb: sdb1
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0)
EXT2-fs (mmcblk0p2): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem) on device 179:2.
devtmpfs: mounted
Freeing unused kernel memory: 240K (c0815000 - c0851000)
INIT: version 2.88 booting
Starting udev
udevd[1489]: starting version 182
EXT2-fs (sda1): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT2-fs (mmcblk0p1): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
hwclock: can't open '/dev/misc/rtc': No such file or directory
Sat Mar  4 00:20:30 UTC 2017
INIT: Entering runlevel: 5misc/rtc': No such fil
Configuring network interfaces... IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
udhcpc (v1.23.1) started
Sending discover...
libphy: fixed-0:01 - Link is Up - 1000/Full
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Sending discover...
Sending select for 192.168.35.106...
Lease of 192.168.35.106 obtained, lease time 600
/etc/udhcpc.d/50default: Adding DNS 192.168.35.1
/etc/udhcpc.d/50default: Adding DNS 84.255.209.79
/etc/udhcpc.d/50default: Adding DNS 84.255.210.79
done.
Starting system message bus: dbus.
Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd
done.
Starting rpcbind daemon...done.
starting statd: done
/etc/rc5.d/S20cs: line 2: $'\r': command not found
Starting Component Server ...
Done.
Starting Distributed Compiler Daemon: distcc.
hwclock: can't open '/dev/misc/rtc': No such file or directory
starting 8 nfsd kernel threads: NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
NFSD: starting 90-second grace period (net c088bb20)
done
starting mountd: done
Starting syslogd/klogd: done
 * Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Daemon: avahi-daemon

QorIQ SDK (FSL Reference Distro) 1.9 p2020rdb /dev/ttyS0

p2020rdb login:
```

Comment: You need to learn about the `help` command.  Try the command `bootm 1000000`

Comment: @sawdust I've upgraded the question, however, after uncompressing image boot process stalls.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Linux on PowerPC, but that Load/Entry Address of 0x0 is suspicious.  What does a normal boot look like?  What's in the U-Boot environment, i.e. the `printenv` command?

Comment: @sawdust I've added requested info into Addendum 2 of question.

Comment: The 0x0 address is okay, but you do need to load a Device Tree blob with your kernel.  If these kernels are all of the same version number, and a just built with different configuration options, then you can load the old DT blob from the MMC device (SDcard?) just like before.  Download the kernel image, then `ext2load mmc 0:1 0xc00000 /boot/dtb_file`, and finally `bootm 0x1000000 - c0000`.  These two commands are extracted from your U-Boot environment variable **bootcmd**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like user @sawdust said, I forgot to load device tree, I did it via `tftpboot`:

```
tftpboot 0xc00000 uImage_test001.dtb
tftpboot uImage_test001
bootm 0x1000000 - 0xc00000
```

And now boots!